# Error starting RSelenium server, undefined error in httr call

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver

I recently upgraded my intel MacBook Pro to MacOS Ventura. The following code was working perfectly before the upgrade, but now I get an error: `Error in checkError(res) : Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE`

```
url <- " " # Web page URL here

# set up server
rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser= "firefox",
                             chromever = NULL,
                             verbose = F,
                             port = free_port())

remDr <- rs_driver_object$client

# open webpage in server
remDr$navigate(url)
```

I've already tried different URLs, so the issue is with the code. One solution I've seen on Substack is to delete the chromever license — I've tried that without success and, besides, my understand is that that shouldn't matter with `chromever` set to `NULL`.

**EDIT**

I should have specified that when I initially wrote this, the error came after `remDr$navigate(url)`. But now — and I haven't done anything different — I get the following error on `rsDriver()`:

```
Warning: Could not determine server status.Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
Check server log for further details.
```